# Added Assigned Image Database to DefaultSessionConfig in HelloAR Example

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

In the existing HelloAR Example, the touch is used to create an object.
I am testing because I want to change to creating objects through Image Tracking without using Touch.

[image]
However, building by adding an Example Database to the Managed Image Database causes the generated DetectedPlaneVisualizer to blink.
Do you have any reason?

Comment: Why do you need a database if you are just using plane detection and not augmented images?

Comment: Instead of entering touch input, I want to create object through image recognition.

Comment: Then you do not need to use `HelleAR` go use `AugmentedImages` example just change the `AugmentedImageVisualizer` script and prefab.

Comment: The reason I'm going to do this is because with Image Recognition, the object trembles after it is created.
So instead of using HelloAR's touch, the thought method is to use Image Recognition to locate and create an Object.

Comment: Okay i understand. If you only want to place objects on top of Augmented Images just disable plane detection it has nothing to do with it. Then track the image instantiate your model at the center of image and anchor it just like you do in `HelloAR` example. Then it wont tremble

Comment: Can you tell me what it's like to hold like HelloAR Example?
Image tracking finds an image, creates an Anchor, and creates an Object at that location. I think Anchor's position, lotion is changing and the object is shaking because I keep track of images.

Comment: Well in Augmented Images every time image features are updated the anchor position changes. Instead just once you create an anchor and dont update it like in HelloAR using `Session.CreateAnchor(Pose pose)`